# Android SDK - Positioning elements in listview row

Tags: android, android-layout

For some reason I'm having a hell of a time with designing using eclipse and android SDK. Making layouts is painfully hard and not as easy as WPF/Visual Studio.

I am trying to accomplish the following:

```
Top: what I have
Bottom: what I want to achieve
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lv2D7.jpg

Current code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:padding="10dip"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:textIsSelectable="false"
    android:id="@+id/line1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    />

<TextView
    android:textIsSelectable="false"
    android:id="@+id/line2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    />

<TextView
    android:textIsSelectable="false"
    android:id="@+id/line3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Edit:

I've also tried using Vertical LinearLayout within a Horizontal LinearLayout but that just produced a lot of errors.

Edit2:

What's with the negative rating?

Edit3:

Tried this link: http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-1.html
Replacing the image with a textview but the date just aligns with the top row.. hmm

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: In the image I linked how can I achieve right aligning the date while also having it centered vertically.

Comment: how to make his layout like the bottom part of the picture he posted. was it really that confusing?

Comment: Did he say anywhere that what he wrote in blockquote relates to the picture and not the xml.

@user2011736: I would recommend using RelativeLayout, LinearLayout won't allow such behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a RelativeLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you. This gives me a good idea on how to design certain stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a `RelativeLayout` for this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:padding="10dip"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:textIsSelectable="false"
    android:id="@+id/line1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    />

<TextView
    android:textIsSelectable="false"
    android:id="@+id/line2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@_id/line1"
    />

<TextView
    android:textIsSelectable="false"
    android:id="@+id/line3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Changes:

Changed `LinearLayout` to `RelativeLayout` used `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"` for the first two lines and `android:layout_below="@+id/line1"` for the second line. Moved the date to the right with `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` and `android:gravity="center_vertical"` Hope this works for what you need.

Comment: I'm glad it works. Its best to use as few `Layouts` and `Views` as possible so the screen can draw faster. So this way you have the same amount of `TextViews` but only one `Layout`